# How to call a custom check on a particular route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Suppose I have multiple routes in my Laravel routes.php Like-

```
Route::post( 'createClan',array('uses'=>'MyClan@createClan'));
Route::post( 'joinClan',array('uses'=>'MyClan@joinClan'));
Route::get( 'myclan', array( 'as' => 'myclan' , 'uses' => 'MyClan@myclan' ));
Route::get( 'clanDetails', array( 'as' => 'clanDetails' , 'uses' => 'MyClan@clanDetails' ));
Route::get( 'myclanDefault', array('as' => 'myclanDefault' , 'uses' => 'MyClan@myclanDefault' ));
```

And I have Controller named 'Common' and I have a 'ValidateRoute' function inside that common like this-

```
public function ValidateRoute($UserId, $form_name){

switch ($form_name)
         {
             case 'createJoin'://Create/Join Clan Menu Option.
                $createJoin=TRUE;
                $clans=  Userclanmapping::where('user_id','=',$UserId)->where('active','=',1)->get(array('clan_id'));
                foreach($clans as $clan)
                {
                    $createJoin=FALSE;
                }
                    return $createJoin;
         }

     }
```

My problem is that I want to call that function before calling that route. And If the function returns true only then I can open that route but if function returns false I should be moved to another route or I should get a message like route not found.

In short, I am trying to apply a custom check on every route. A route is only accessible only if it fulfills that conditions.

I tried this code-

```
Route::get( 'myclanDefault', array( 'before'=>'common:ValidateMenuOptions(Session::get(\'userid\'),\'createJoin\'))','as' => 'myclanDefault' , 'uses' => 'MyClan@myclanDefault' ));
```

But this didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `route filters` per route basis using something like this:

```
// In filters.php
Route::filter('myclanDefaultFilter', function($route, $request){
    // ...
    if(someCondition) {
        return Redirect::route('routeName');
    }
});
```

Then declare the `route` like this:

```
Route::get(
    'myclanDefault',
    array(
        'before' => 'myclanDefaultFilter',
        'as' => 'myclanDefault',
        'uses' => 'MyClan@myclanDefault' 
    )
);
```

Now before `myclanDefault` is dispatched to the action the `myclanDefaultFilter` filter will run first and you may redirect from that filter depending a certain condition.

Also, you may declare a global `before event` for all the routes using something like this:

```
App::before(function($request){
    // This event will fire for every route
    // before they take any further action
});
```